# Any way to find in between?

Tags: php, mysql

First i need to say sorry, because previously system / database design to store data in group like >>> A1 - A8 (means Row A No.1 to Row A No.8) or B4 - B12 (means Row B No.4 to Row B No.12)
in a string format and store in database.

example

========================
=     seat      =     condition     =
========================
=   A1 - A8   =        Good       =
=  B4 - B12  =          Bad        =
========================

but now system is changed!! (after a year) and need to identify each of it 1 by 1, it means now the user enter A4, system able to return condition of it (Good) or enter A20 system return not found

is there any way (coding side or sql statement) to fulfill this NEW requirement without change database design? because if change on database side it will need to change the way it store data too (more work have to be done)

i hope you guys understand my question. By the way, i'm using PHP and mySQL.

Comment: It's possible but not easily on the MYSQL query. It would be better to select * from db and use php to work it out.    Can a row in the database go from a1 - b8?  Do all rows have the same number of seats?  If only 1 seat is good in a row is it written a1-a4 bad a5-a5 good a6-a8 bad?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to extract the row by the first character e.g 'A' then convert the '1' to '8' into a range (A1,A2...,A8) then do an in_array to find if they exist in the array. seems very complicated and expensive solution though

Comment: so sad to heard about this.... actually i have a solution but it really need me to change database design which i try to avoid here, thanks anyway varun

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much bad database design and you should consider changing. For now, the logic would be something like:

1. Break the user input to alphabet and number - let's say `user_seat_letter`
   and `user_seat_number`
2. Get the seat (along with the `Condition`) from the table
3. Break it at `-`
4. Then break it by alphabet and number - let's say `row_seat_letter1`,
   `row_seat_number1` and `row_seat_letter2`, `row_seat_number2`
5. i) If `user_seat_letter` does not match `row_seat_letter1`, fetch the next
   seat from the table
   ii) Else if the seat matches, check if
   `user_seat_number` equal to and between `row_seat_number1` and
   `row_seat_number2`

   ```
        a) If true, return the `Condition` of that row
        b) Else return 'Not Found'
   ```

   iii) Else return 'Not Found'

Comment: yes, i accept the database design is poor coz client willing to pay very cheap price, and now wanted to change with minimum very low price, that's why i looking for any ideal of solution, by the way this deal with some "business relationship" inside so i'm also headache with this now. thanks for your suggestion Cheezburdger